# How to cancel jQuery.click from pure javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To make it simple:

I have a webpage. It has some scripts, one of which bind a click event to an <a> tag.

```
$('#someId').click(function() {
    ......
});
```

I want to add a **pure javascript** to this page (I'm not allowed to modify other js files) and take control of the click event. What I have tried is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('someId').onclick = function (event) {
    if (someCondition) {
        // cancel this click event 
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.cancel = true;
        return false;
    } else {
        // do something else.
    }
};
```

This piece of code seems not working. I need some help.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for my ambiguous language. By "pure javascript" I mean "using basic javascript manipulations instead of jQuery methods."

Comment: Why does your solution need to be in "pure JavaScript"?  Why can't you just do `$('#someId').off('click')` and then re-bind it?

Comment: What do you mean by ***"seems not working"***?

Comment: There's nothing "impure JavaScript" about using jQuery. Perhaps you mean you want only to use DOM methods.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I assume he meant [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) :-)

Comment: Are you trying to remove the need to include jQuery? If not you might as well use the jQuery methods available to you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right. I want to find a way that work this problem out without jQuery.

Comment: @Lion: You can't, see my answer for why. But that's okay, there's no *reason* to, if jQuery is loaded on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more possible solution, but unfortunately it has some browser compatibility issues. The point is to use css `pointer-events` property and `onmousedown` event like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert('jquery');
});

var i = 0;
btn.onmousedown = function(ev) {
    if (i++ % 2 == 0) {
        btn.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // disable clicks

        setTimeout(function() {
            btn.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'; // enable back in 500 ms
        }, 500);
    }
};
```

See compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) and the demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/54ZWC/1/)

For IE you can try element `disabled` property in a same way.

And sure it's better to use jQuery for this (if it is used already in your project)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to add a pure javascript to this page (I'm not allowed to modify other js files) and take control of the click event.

If the code is going to be on that page, it can use jQuery, which is good because that's also the only way you can unregister the jQuery-registered handler:

```
$("#someId").off("click").on("click", function() {
    // Your new code here
});
```

Calling `.off("click")` on an element removes **all** jQuery-registered `click` handlers from that element.

That said, usually there's a better approach than clobbering the handlers registered by other code on the page.

---

Why you can't unregister the jQuery-registered handler without using jQuery: The first time a particular event is hooked on a particular element via jQuery, jQuery registers **one** handler (its own) to use for that event on that element; if more handlers are attached, it just adds them to its own internal list, it doesn't register those with the DOM. Instead, when the DOM event is fired, jQuery walks through its list of handlers and triggers them.

To unregister jQuery's actual handler for the event on the element, you'd have to get a reference to the specific function instance jQuery used when registering it. (`removeEventListener` doesn't have the equivalent of the above "clear all of them"). *That* reference is only available from data structures inside jQuery's closure, so you can't get at it without using jQuery.

---

> What should I do if other handlers need to resume to be executed under some circumstances in the $.on() block?

Ah, that's much more difficult. It all depends on more of the context than is present in your question. Some options:

1. By far the best thing is to modify the other code that is handling clicks. But I understand you're saying you can't do that.
2. jQuery calls handlers in the order they were registered (this is one reason it handles calling multiple handlers itself; different browsers do things in different orders). So if you can hook `click` on `#someId` **before** the other code does, then you can reliably use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent other handlers from being called. That won't work, of course, if your handler isn't first in the list, because the other handlers will have been called first.
3. If there's an element within the `#someId` element that completely fills it, you can hook `click` on *that* element instead, and then use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up to the `#someId` element.
4. And of course, if there *isn't* an element like #3, you could probably insert one (dynamically, with code) and move `#someId`'s contents into it, so you could inject your handler into the bubbling.
5. You can dive into jQuery's internals and figure out how to access the event handler chain and manipulate it. It used to be quite easy; I think recent versions have made it harder. This would be, of course, going into undocumented territory that could change with any "dot" release.

Comment: What should I do if other handlers need to resume to be executed under some circumstances in the $.on() block?

Comment: @Lion: It's hard to say without more context. I've added some options to the answer. Good luck,

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the click listener after the page has loaded.

```
window.onload=function(){
    //your code here.
};
```

If you are trying to disable the button after the click, add the 'disabled' property to the button and remove the click listener.

```
document.getElementById('someId').onclick = null;
document.getElementById('someId').disabled = true;
```